# Still manual configuration for using the android maven plugin?

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

I'm learning how to use maven for android development, and just to be sure I'm on the right track.
I found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-development-maven) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/s70487s/android-research/maven)
that the archetype is not still on the standard catalog, so one has to edit ~/.m2/settings.xml for having access to android-maven-plugin.
Well, I can cope with it, as it is a one-time task.

But the tutorials explain that

1. the pom.xml must be manually created for every project. Is this alright? Not seems very user friendly ! (Yes I know I can have a template pom.xml, but it still seems not very professional to me).
2. the directory tree for the project must be created with the android tool of de Android-SDK. Is this alright?

Update: more issues on the [android-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424569/issues-with-android-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

and then select from suggested archetypes.
Here is what this command yields for me:

```
89: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-library-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android library)
90: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android application)
91: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-release (Creates a skeleton for an Android application,
    instrumentation tests and ready-to-publish application on releases.)
92: remote -> de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-with-test (Creates a skeleton for an Android application and instrumentation tests)
```

Comment: My mvn tool only lists 41 archetypes. mvn --version is 3.0.4 on Mac OS X. Is my problem on the mvn version or I'm missing to add something to some configuration file? Thnx.

Comment: Possible answer can be found here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-config-build.html#android-dev-sect-repository-install
But sorry, I'm not sure.

Comment: Added complete mvn commandline -D flags for generating the android project

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetype
```

in case the 89-92 archetypes are no listed.