# issues with android-maven-plugin

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin

(After really many hours trying it,  I finally resign.)

Alright:

-1. I do

```
mvn    -X   archetype:generate   -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-release 
-DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.9                           
-DgroupId=org.me -DartifactId=myAndroidApp     -Demulator=myEmu
-Dplatform=10
```

-2. First issue: you must manually edit top-level pom.xml to add

```
< properties>
< platform.version>  2.3.3  < /platform.version>
```

< /properties>

despite it is a straightforward relationship between `-Dplatform=10` and 2.3.3

-3. (possibly) Second issue (instrumentation tests: myAndroidApp-it dir.)
You have to  edit AndroidManifest.xml and check whether the `android:targetPackage` value
is right

-4. Third issue (**which I couldn't be able to resolve**). Problems with zipaligned-classifier dependencies
in the instrumentation tests (myAndroidApp-it dir.)

When doing `mvn install`

-4.1

```
    [WARNING] The POM for org.me:myAndroidApp:apk:${zipaligned-classifier}:1.0-SNAPSHOT 

is missing, no dependency information available

[WARNING] The POM for org.me:myAndroidApp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT 

is missing, no dependency information available
```

-4.2

```
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myAndroidApp-it: 
    Could not resolve dependencies for 
project org.me:myAndroidApp-it:apk:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
    The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.me:myAndroidApp:apk:${zipaligned-classifier}:1.0-SNAPSHOT, org.me:myAndroidApp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
    Could not find artifact org.me:myAndroidApp:apk:${zipaligned-classifier}:1.0-
```

Thanks

Update: reported the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=345&thanks=345&ts=1358700408)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing adding this in your `<Properties>` section may fix the first warning:

```
<zipaligned-classifier>aligned</zipaligned-classifier>
```

Then run mvn install in your myAndroidApp project. Ensure the build is successful for your app (don't care you myAndroidApp-it for now), and then take a look to your local repo to see the artifacts that where installed. (`<USER_HOME>/.m2/repository/org/me`)

For your second warning : ensure you have something like this in dependencies of myAndroidApp-it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>myAndroidApp</artifactId>
    <type>apk</type>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependency>
```

Depending on the artifacts that where installed you may need to add a classifier for this dependency (since you didn't post your pom.xml it's difficult to say what will be installed by mvn).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>myAndroidApp</artifactId>
    <type>apk</type>
    <classifier>${zipaligned-classifier}</classfier>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I had to leave empty `<zipaligned-classifier> </zipaligned-classifier>` as mvn doesn't generate myAndroidApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.apk-aligned but just myAndroid.......apk

Comment: but now there is another problem: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.me.test/org.me.HelloAndroidActivity }

Comment: I can't understand why the auto-generated project by the android-maven-pluggin just compiles without **any** human intervention. Now I will have to look inside **its** .java test files. (Patience)

Comment: I guess you solved my initial question. So I accept it. Thanks a lot.